# How can I return an unsigned integer as a binary value in C?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit, 16-bit

More specifically, I need to make a function `float_16(unsigned sign, unsigned exp, unsigned frac)`, that returns a `bit16` representation (*bit16 is a typedef unsigned integer*) of a number given a sign, exponent, and fraction values as unsigned integers.

I have the following preamble:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    typedef unsigned int bit16;
    bit16 a;
    a = 0xABCD; // 1010 1011 1100 1101 in binary = 43981

    printf("Sign is: %d",extractSign(a));
    printf(" ");
    printf("Exponent is: %d",extractExp(a));
    printf(" ");
    printf("Fraction is: %d",extractFrac(a));
    …
}
```

In my main program, and these values are retrieved by the functions in a separate C file:

```
int extractSign(bit16 x) //significant bit
{
    return (x >> 15) & 0x0001; // 0x0001 is mask for 1 bit
}

int extractExp(bit16 x) // 7 bits
{
    return (x >> 8) & 0x007F; // 0x007F is mask for 7 bits
}

int extractFrac(bit16 x) // 8 bit fraction field
{
    return x & 0x00FF; // 0x00FF is mask for 8 bits
}
```

How would I be able to use these values to fulfill what is being asked here?

Comment: Why would you need the sign bit, if it is unsigned? Also, it's not clear what you are asking.

Comment: To extract the bits you right shift and AND. To reverse the process, you left shift and OR.

Comment: @user3386109 how can I reverse it when the numbers are in decimal format?

Comment: I assume that you are trying to implement the `float_16` function, whose prototype is given in the first line of the question. The `sign` argument will be either 0 or 1, the `exp` argument will be a number between 0 and 127, and the `frac` will be a number between 0 and 255. There is no decimal format involved, unless a user is providing the numbers in string form. And there is no mention in your question that you need to process user input.

Comment: Take a look [HERE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-precision_floating-point_format). It gives you all things you need to use sign, exp and fraction you already have.

Comment: Unisgned integers don't have mantissa and exponent... only floating point numbers have that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_type).

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef unsigned short bit16; // On my computer, sizeof (int) == 4, while sizeof (short) == 2

union floating_point
{
    bit16 a;
    struct
    {
        unsigned frac : 8;
        unsigned exp : 7;
        unsigned sign : 1;
    } guts;
};

bit16 float_16 (unsigned sign, unsigned exp, unsigned frac);
unsigned extractSign (bit16 a);
unsigned extractExp (bit16 a);
unsigned extractFrac (bit16 a);

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    bit16 a = 0xABCD;
    printf("%d\n",a == float_16(extractSign(a),extractExp(a),extractFrac(a)));
    printf("Sign is: %u\n",extractSign(a));
    printf("Exponent is: %u\n",extractExp(a));
    printf("Fraction is: %u\n",extractFrac(a));
    return 0;
}

bit16 float_16 (unsigned sign, unsigned exp, unsigned frac)
{
    union floating_point value;
    value.guts.sign=sign;
    value.guts.exp=exp;
    value.guts.frac=frac;
    return value.a;
}

unsigned extractSign (bit16 a)
{
    union floating_point value;
    value.a=a;
    return value.guts.sign;
}

unsigned extractExp (bit16 a)
{
    union floating_point value;
    value.a=a;
    return value.guts.exp;
}

unsigned extractFrac (bit16 a)
{
    union floating_point value;
    value.a=a;
    return value.guts.frac;
}
```

Comment: You can use unions of bitfield when you know exactly how the compiler implements their layout in memory.  This is a complete compiler dependant solution.

Comment: @LuisColorado As I know, this is an undefined behavior, but is widely supported.

Comment: I know, but as such, it's prone to U.B.